# How can I search on time ranges in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have lots of data that looks like this:

```
{
"timestamp": "2015-04-23T14:35:43.511Z",
"component1Health": "false",
"area": "squad1"
}

{
"timestamp": "2015-04-23T18:03:22.911Z",
"component1Health": "true",
"area": "squad7"
}
```

I want to search on, say, all instances of

```
"component1Health": "false"
```

that occurred on any weekday between 8am and 8pm.

The docs at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html
show that it's easy to search on date ranges, eg

```
"range" : {
"timestamp" : {
    "gt" : "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
    "lt" : "2014-01-07 00:00:00"
    }
}
```

but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong to extract the time. I've been through stackoverflow and the es forum etc but I can't crack it.

Can you help?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Your example query looks fine. Can you add real documents and real queries that you tried but did not work?

Comment: The query is from elastic's documentation, and yes works fine for date ranges --- but I want time ranges, and I can't see how to 'extract' the time from the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve that with a date range. A simple solution would be indexing a new integer field that contains the hour of day. So that your two documents look like:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2015-04-23T14:35:43.511Z",
  "hourOfTheDay": 14,
  "component1Health": "false",
  "area": "squad1"
}

{
  "timestamp": "2015-04-23T18:03:22.911Z",
  "hourOfTheDay": 18,
  "component1Health": "true",
  "area": "squad7"
}
```

And now you can do a similar range filter on that new field that look like:

```
"range" : {
  "hourOfTheDay" : {
     "gt" : 7,
     "lt" : 21
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks yes it is certainly do-able. Coming from an SQL background, it's disappointing, but OTOH it will make the searching dead easy.

Comment: You _can_ get it working by using a script filter, but you really shouldn't, as it would be slow. It would be the equivalent to a sequential scan in SQL, unless you create a functional index for it, which moliware is essentially recommending the Elasticsearch equivalent for.

Comment: Thanks Alex, makes sense. To help me scratch the itch - I've been trying for several days -  how would you do it with a script filter?